# MassTransit RMQ scheduling scheduled but not sent

Tags: rabbitmq, scheduling, masstransit

I'm trying to implement scheduling mechanism by the `masstransit/rabbitmq`.

I've added the configuration as stated in the docs:

```
Uri schedulerEndpoint = new (Constants.MassTransit.SchedulerEndpoint);

services.AddMassTransit(mtConfiguration =>
{
    mtConfiguration.AddMessageScheduler(schedulerEndpoint);

    mtConfiguration.AddSagaStateMachine<ArcStateMachine, ArcProcess>(typeof(ArcSagaDefinition))
        .Endpoint(e => e.Name = massTransitConfiguration.SagaQueueName)
        .MongoDbRepository(mongoDbConfiguration.ConnectionString, r =>
        {
            r.DatabaseName = mongoDbConfiguration.DbName;
            r.CollectionName = mongoDbConfiguration.CollectionName;
        });

    mtConfiguration.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseMessageScheduler(schedulerEndpoint);

        cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqConfiguration.Host), hst =>
        {
            hst.Username(rabbitMqConfiguration.Username);
            hst.Password(rabbitMqConfiguration.Password);
        });

            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

Then I'm sending a scheduled message using the `Bus`:

```
DateTime messageScheduleTime = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
await _MessageScheduler.SchedulePublish<ScheduledMessage>(messageScheduleTime, new
{
    ActivationId = context.Data.ActivationId
});
```

`_MessageCheduler` is the `IMessageScheduler` instance.

I do see the Scheduler queue receive the scheduled message and I see the correct `scheduledTime` property in it but the message does not reach the state machine whenever its schedule should fire. Seems like I'm missing something in the configuration or some MassTransit service that is not started.

Please, assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *actually read the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/rabbitmq-delayed.html)* you would see that `UseDelayedMessageScheduler` is the proper configuration to use RabbitMQ for scheduling. And `AddDelayedMessageScheduler` for the container-based `IMessageScheduler` registration.

Comment: I used this documentation as a reference: https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/scheduling-api.html. Thanks for the answer. It worked. Could you also direct me to the documentation on how to cancel the scheduled publish? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Messages scheduled using the broker cannot be canceled. Which is also pointed out on the documentation page I linked in bright yellow.

Comment: Should it then be implemented differently to have an option of cancelling the schedule?

Comment: If you want to be able to cancel scheduled messages, you'd have to use Quartz.NET or Hangfire, which is a more involved setup but also documented, along with sample projects.

Comment: I understood. Thanks a lot for your assistance.